# How to have two (or more) text sections in CheckedTextView? Android

Tags: java, android, xml

How do I get two strings onto one CheckedTextView? Obviously, with the blow code I get the error "Duplicate attribute text.

activity.xml

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/GEDTrainingReq1"
    style="@style/SideCheckedText"
    android:text="@string/days_left"
    android:text="@string/days_left_ged"/>
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="days_left">Days Left:</string>
<string name="days_left_ged">20</string>
```

I want it to look like:

ICON  Days Left: 20

I need the 20 (days_left_ged) to be a separate string so I can change the number later in my java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use string formatting.

```
<string name="days_left_fmt">Days left: %1$d</string>
```

Where `%1$d` is a decimal number.

Then, format the string by calling `getString(int, Object...)`.

For example:

```
int days = 20;
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.days_left_fmt, days);
checkedTextView.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate multiple strings with in the XML, you should do it in the Java code instead.